# How to specify multiple text delimiters from CSV using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am new to Python and I need help on parsing the following CSV file using Python programming language. I have the csv file 
**case.csv**

```
~`Value~`,~`CaseId~`
~`the,data ~ has all `characters~`,~`1~`
~`and~`,~`2~
```

I used the following Python code to parse it.  However, quotechar is allowing only one character but my file has 2 char text qualifier **~`**.

```
import csv
with open("C:\CSVFiles\WORDS.csv","rt") as f:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',',quotechar="~")
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

When I tried passing with multiple characters in the quotechar, I am getting the following error.

```
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/Nv/CSV", line 4, in <module>
    csv_reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',',quotechar="~`")
TypeError: "quotechar" must be a 1-character string
```

Please suggest to me how to parse multi-text qualifier CSV in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping the characters after you read the file

```
import csv
with open("C:\CSVFiles\WORDS.csv","rt") as f:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        line = [x.strip('`~')) for x in line]
```

Comment: my `line` returns as a list and can not be stripped, might need to join first

Comment: @Ph better with list comprehension?

Comment: this wills parse the file incorrectly in case the value having embedded "," inside
Ex:
```~`a,bc~`,~`1~```

Comment: @chand, then just read file and handle it yourself, change quote to `"` then read using `StringIO` and csv reader

Comment: @chand In that example, you would set `quotechar='~'`. Your post does not have consistent quote characters

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for. I'm new to this as well but what I did was simply replacing ur "`~" to normal quote for each line then do as per what you have intended.

```
f = open("C:\CSVFiles\WORDS.csv", "rb")
fo = open("C:\CSVFiles\WORDS2.csv", "wb")

for line in f:
    fo.write(line.replace("~`", "\""))

f.close()
fo.close()

with open("C:\CSVFiles\WORDS2.csv","rt") as f:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',',quotechar="\"")

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

Cheers :)

Comment: note: it is better to  use `with` for file handling, then you don't have to close anything yourself